# Getting IndexError: list index out of range error while parsing HTML in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am trying to get a list of neighboorhoods for Singapore into a dataframe. I am using BeautifulSoup package. But, when I run I am getting IndexError : list out of range error. Couldn't quite follow why I am getting this. I tried a different city (say Kuala Lumpur) from the same Wiki page and it is working fine. Could anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

```
sg_data = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_in_Singapore").text
sg_soup = BeautifulSoup(sg_data, 'html.parser')

sg_neighborhoodList = []

for row in sg_soup.find_all("div", class_="mw-category")[0].findAll("li"):
  sg_neighborhoodList.append(row.text)
```

And here is the error

---

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 for row in sg_soup.find_all("div", class_="mw-category")[0].findAll("li"):
>         2   sg_neighborhoodList.append(row.text)
>         3
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are there any divs with that class description on the page. May be it does not register any list items because there is not div element with class mw-category. May be try "mw-parser-output"?

Comment: "mw-parser-output" worked. Yes, @S.Kuiter that was the issue. I was trying to read that even didnt exist !! And "mw-parser-output" worked, but requires a lot of cleaning. Thanks much for that valuable insight.

Answer (score 0):

It is  may be because  the html page that you have read, there is no div with a class called "mw-category". So it is empty and 0 index of empty is index out of range. Try changing it to some other class name.